# Unity3d GUI temperature bar filling amount

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a Temperature Bar in my game using the new Unity GUI system.

First I created an image named temperature in the scene view and placed my bar image on it.

Next I created this added this script to it:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TemperatureBar1 : MonoBehaviour {

    public Image temperatureBar1;

    void Update () {
        temperatureBar1.fillAmount = (((float)thermoPowerControlPanel.temperature1) / 100);
    }
}
```

Finally, in the scene view a new slot appeared to insert this temperatureBar1 image where I added the temperature image I created before.

The problem is that the bar never fills down or up, despite receiving a value between 0-1 every frame, that value is working fine and stored here:

```
((thermoPowerControlPanel.temperature1) / 100)
```

Can you help?

Comment: What Fill Method and Fill Origin you have on this Image?

Comment: Also what range of value thermoPowerControlPanel.temperature1 has?

Comment: It ranges from 0 to 100 that it why I divided by 100 to get a value on the range of 0-1

Comment: I just have one method on this image which is the Fill Amount

Comment: You dont understand me, when you select Image as Filled you have to choose Fill Method: Horizontal, Vertical, Radial 90 ...

Comment: temperature1 and fillamount are a float or real?

Comment: temperature is real. Maybe I am missing something because I did not choose any Fill Method

Comment: Is that something you do on the scene view?

Comment: Yes, it is done with inspector.

Comment: Yet another abandoned question :(

Comment: I just did that you said but the Fill Amount is only 0 or 1 , never the values in between..

Comment: I changed this to send a float but did not fixed:

Comment: temperatureBar1.fillAmount = (float)((thermoPowerControlPanel.temperature1) / 100);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay from your comments I think I know what is the problem. You didnt se the Image Type as Filled. To do so check this:

[image]

To be able to use `fillAmount` you need to set the Image Type to Filled.

Comment: I just did What you said but the Fill Amount is only 0 or 1 , never the values in between despite the fact that the value I am feeding ranges from 0:0,1:0,2...1

Comment: I gave you the answer but if you can help me I would be appreciated.

Comment: @GrowAnimation I see, then your values in division all were ints. I didnt think about it.

Comment: it's an incredibly handy feature Unity added!

Comment: @JoeBlow agreed, it has also radial method that can be used as cooldowns and actualy in my current project we use it.